# R3InjectorError No provider for NgbDropdown

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9, angular-ivy

I have a shared module A where I import and export NgbDropdownModule

```
import { ... NgbDatepickerModule, NgbDropdownModule, NgbModalModule ...} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports: [...NgbDropdownModule...]

exports: [...NgbDropdownModule...]
```

In module B I just import module A and up to Angular 9 everything worked fine.
I used components from A, but also ngbDropdown directly.

After upgrading to Angular 9, I receive following error when module B is lazy loaded:

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(BModule)[NgbDropdown -> NgbDropdown -> NgbDropdown -> NgbDropdown]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbDropdown!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:60672:25)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:71020:33)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:71020:33)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:71020:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:84306:33)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:71020:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.push../node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:84306:33)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:82620:35)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:63536:39)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:51000/vendor.js:73885:12)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Module A registered in app.modules?

Comment: It's imported in app.module, module B is lazy loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, someone put Dropdown instead of ngbDropdown in one of the components.

Like I saw on some other posts, this problem usually exists if hierarchy of ngbDropdown->ngbDropdownToggle->ngbDropdownMenu is not respected.